# Failing to compile capnproto under visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, capnproto

I am following the instructions from the link below for compiling capnproto under visual studio 2019.
https://capnproto.org/install.html

When I try to build the solution "ALL_BUILD" in step 6, it fails. The first error that I see in the log is that it cannot find the file "win32-api-version.h" from kj/debug.c++

Is there some project setting that i am missing?

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Checking Build System
2>------ Build started: Project: kj, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: kj-gzip, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>------ Skipped Build: Project: Continuous, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
5>------ Skipped Build: Project: Experimental, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
5>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
6>------ Skipped Build: Project: Nightly, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
6>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
7>------ Skipped Build: Project: NightlyMemoryCheck, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
7>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
8>------ Skipped Build: Project: RUN_TESTS, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
8>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
2>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/snjvs/capnproto-c++-win32-0.10.0/capnproto-c++-0.10.0/src/kj/CMakeLists.txt
3>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/snjvs/capnproto-c++-win32-0.10.0/capnproto-c++-0.10.0/src/kj/CMakeLists.txt
3>gzip.c++
2>array.c++
2>list.c++
3>kj-gzip.vcxproj -> C:\Users\snjvs\capnproto-c++-win32-0.10.0\capnproto-c++-0.10.0\src\kj\Debug\kj-gzip.lib
2>common.c++
2>debug.c++
****2>C:\Users\snjvs\capnproto-c++-win32-0.10.0\capnproto-c++-0.10.0\src\kj\debug.c++(23,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'win32-api-version.h': No such file or directory****
2>exception.c++
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Cap'n Proto's 0.10.0 release, which just went out a few days ago. This file was not included in the release package. CI didn't catch it because CI runs directly from git. Ugh.

I will try to build a 0.10.1 release today.

EDIT: 0.10.1 is now released, fixing this issue. Get it here: https://capnproto.org/install.html

Comment: Thanks, that works to build the ALL_BUILD solution. However, the build of install failed with the missing command "setlocal". I do see the .lib files in files in the build directory under src/{capnp,kj}/Debug. I am using CMake 3.23.2
```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB3073 The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake

:VCEnd" exited with code 1. INSTALL C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 155 
```

Comment: I tried searching for solution and this did *NOT* work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/266423/error-when-installing-build.html

Comment: Hi @SanjeevSingh, it sounds like you're hitting a different issue now, and it's an issue that might be more about cmake than Cap'n Proto. I would recommend posting a new question.